# In Clojure how can I implement standard Clojure collection interfaces on my own records and types?

Tags: clojure

I wish to create an abstraction which represents a database table, but which can be accessed using all the usual Clojure seq and conj and all that fancy stuff. Is there a protocol I need to add?

Comment: Is there a reason why a vector of records is insufficient as a representation? (I mean this as a serious question, not snark). All of closure's API would work with such an abstraction. From clojure's rationale http://clojure.org/rationale - "It is better to have 100 functions operate on one data structure than to have 10 functions operate on 10 data structures." - Alan J. Perlis

Comment: The reason is that when I add an item to the vector I want the item to be automatically persisted to a datastore, and there is no way I can hide that without reimplementing conj or cons or whatever the add function is for Vectors.

Comment: Be super, super careful with this sort of thing. If you DB isn't immutable you're basically lying about your semantics to Clojure this can go wrong very quickly. Most of Clojure is built on the idea that collections are immutable. As such a lot of assumptions are made about how certain functions perform. For instance, using conj on a collection should not change the collection. It should return a new collection. Breaking this rule could cause Clojure's functions to fail in very strange ways.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. The protocol is defined by the Java interface `clojure.lang.ISeq`. You may want to extend `clojure.lang.ASeq` which provides an abstract implementation of it.

Here is an example: a `seq` abstraction of a resource which is closable and is closed automatically when the `seq` ends. (Not rigorously tested)

```
(deftype CloseableSeq [delegate-seq close-fn]
  clojure.lang.ISeq
    (next [this]
      (if-let [n (next delegate-seq)]
        (CloseableSeq. n close-fn)
        (.close this)))
    (first [this] (if-let [f (first delegate-seq)] f (.close this)))
    (more [this] (if-let [n (next this)] n '()))
    (cons [this obj] (CloseableSeq. (cons obj delegate-seq) close-fn))
    (count [this] (count delegate-seq))
    (empty [this] (CloseableSeq. '() close-fn))
    (equiv [this obj] (= delegate-seq obj))
  clojure.lang.Seqable 
    (seq [this] this)
  java.io.Closeable
    (close [this] (close-fn)))
```

Comment: So do I use the extendprotocol syntax?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Implementation of `seq` doesn't seem to be right, because when invoked on an empty sequence `seq` should return nil, whereas here you simply return the original sequence.